# Unable to invoke [HttpPost] web api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, api, webapi

Below is my post method

```
[HttpPost]
public string Happay(string fileName) 
{
    //some code
}
```

When I try to invoke it from postman using this URL `https://localhost:44313/SAPAPI/Happay?fileName=Payload1` it works but when I try to do the same from the browser it give me an exception that says

> Resource not found

I removed the `[HttpPost]` attribute from the top an then I was able to invoke the method from the browser.

Comment: How are you invoking from browser ? If you are just requesting that URL, it's a GET

Answer (score 1):

The QueryString (in your case `?fileName=Payload1`) is only applicable for GET requests.

In case of POST you can provide parameters

- as part of the request route, like `POST /SAPAPI/Happay/Payload1`
- as a request body, like `filename=Payload1` as raw
- as a request header, like `"x-file-name": "Payload1"`

Depending on the mode you need to specify from where do you expect the parameter

- `public string Happay([FromRoute]string fileName)`
- `public string Happay([FromBody]string fileName)`
- `public string Happay([FromHeader(Name = "x-file-name")]string fileName)`

---

| Parameter as | Sample | Code change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Route | `POST /SAPAPI/Happay/Payload1` | `[FromRoute(Name="fileName")]string fileName` |
| Body | `fileName=Payload1` | `[FromBody(Name="fileName")]string fileName` |
| Header | `"x-file-name": "Payload1"` | `[FromHeader(Name="x-file-name")]string fileName` |

Answer (score -1):

Add [FromBody] before the parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
public string Happay([FromBody] string fileName) 
{
    //some code
}
```

Comment: But the fileName parameter is in the URI, not the body.

Comment: If it is from url you can use httpget and change frombody to fromuri or you can simply add [HttpGet("{parametername}"]

Answer (score -1):

If you are calling the url from a browser, this is a GET request. Please learn more about REST.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: @MattEvans, I can't write a comment because my reputation is below 50.